# Keep CSS After InnerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, innerhtml

I have this code. I use javascript to insert a row to the table, and one row has one option inside it.

```js
function myCreateFunction() {
  var table = document.getElementById("customers2");
  var row = table.insertRow(1);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
  cell1.innerHTML = "<div class='form-group'><div class='col-md-6 col-xs-12'><select id='slc' name='slc' class='form-control select' data-live-search='true'><option value=''>-Test-</option></select></div></div>";
  cell2.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='sl' name='sl[]' class='form-control' placeholder='Điền vào số lượng sản phẩm...' />";
  cell3.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='g' name='g[]' class='form-control' placeholder='Điền vào giá bán sản phẩm...' />";
  cell4.innerHTML = "<input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='myDeleteFunction(this)' class='btn btn-danger'>";
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-body">
  <table id="customers2" class="table datatable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Tên sản phẩm </th>
        <th>Số lượng</th>
        <th>Giá bán</th>
        <th>Xóa dòng</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
              <select id="slc" name="slc" class="form-control select" data-live-search="true" onchange="customer_theo_enterprise(this.value);">
                                        <option value="">-Test option here-</option>
                                        </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" id="sl" name="sl[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Điền vào số lượng sản phẩm..." /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="g" name="g[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Điền vào giá bán sản phẩm..." /></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="myDeleteFunction(this)" class="btn btn-danger"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <input type="button" onclick="myCreateFunction()" value="Thêm dòng" class="btn btn-primary">
</div>
```

And the next added row does not have CSS, that's my problem.

Here is the result. The first freshly inserted row doesn't have any CSS, but the second one has it.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "lost CSS"?

Comment: can you please explain what is the problem?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/f4p8vxn0/ it should work.

Comment: For example i have the css color is red. And after innerHTML it is not red

Comment: Please post the whole problem in a fiddle or codepen: setting styled DOM elements with innerHTML should work, as i stated above. I suspect this is a larger problem due to your HTML and your CSS.

Comment: You need to add your css code then .. maybe the selector is different

Comment: Since you are having only one option set, which is selected, you are not seeing the `color` applied to the option.. Try including multiple options and that should work.. **[Here's the sample fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/duj4efh5/)**

Comment: I just upadate my question. thank you guys

Comment: also, you shouldn't be using a table for styling a form.

Comment: Your code is working fine. [Check here](https://jsfiddle.net/Jaydeep_Mor/1qamtk26/).

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't clear, also, it's not providing all the information necessary to answer.
However, if I understood what you're trying to accomplish, your problem is that you have this code that generate a select into table row, and you want the options to have a certain text color.
It works, just consider the selected option style should be changed differently.

```js
var table = document.getElementById("customers2");
            var row   = table.insertRow(0);
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            cell1.innerHTML = "<div class='form-group'><div class='col-md-6 col-xs-12'><select id='slc1' name='slc1' class='form-control select' data-live-search='true'  ><option value='check' style='color: #000;'>Click here</option><option value='check' style='color: #fff;'><option value='check' style='color: #888;'>Click here</option>Click here</option></select></div></div>"
```

```html
<table id="customers2">

</table>
```